# PHP - Inserir imagem do banco de dados no pdf gerado via fpdf

Tags: php, html, pdf, fpdf

Estou utilizando o sistema fpdf para gerar arquivos pdf através de um formulario html. Porém gostaria de inserir no pdf uma imagem que está upada no banco de dados mysql.

A sintese para inserir imagem no pdf é:

```html
$pdf->Image('logo.png',18,13,33);
```